# How to check if string contains a certain substring like [3:0]

Tags: java, regex, string, match, contains

I am working on a project where i need to search for a particular string token and find if this token has the [3:0] format of number, how can i check it? i searched for reference on stack overflow, i could find how to search "{my string }:" in a string like the following:

```
String myStr = "this is {my string: } ok";
if (myStr.trim().contains("{my string: }")) {
    //Do something.
}
```

But, could not find how to search if a string contains a number in the regular expression, i tried using the following, but it did not work:

```
String myStr = "this is [3 string: ] ok";
if (myStr.trim().contains("[\\d string: ]")) {
    //Do something.
}
```

Please help!

Comment: It should be `\\[(\\d+)\\]`

Comment: `String#contains` does not parse regular expressions.

Comment: The characters `[]` are special in regular expressions. So after you switch to the appropriate method in `String`, take a look at the [regex tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info), there is a lot of information there about regular expressions.

Comment: I tried but its not working:

String myStr1 = "this is [3 string: ] ok";
                            if (myStr1.trim().contains("\\[(\\d+) string: \\]")) {
                                //Do something.
                                System.out.println("IT IS HERE!");
                            }

Comment: As a tip: try a regEx parser online, e.g. http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
for "[int:int]" use \\[\\d*:\\d*\\]  it's working
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a regex inside `String#contains`, instead, use `.matches()` with a regex.

**To match `[3 string: ]`-like patterns inside larger strings** (where `string` is a literal word `string`), use a regex like `(?s).*\\[\\d+\\s+string:\\s*\\].*`:

```
String myStr = "this is [3 string: ] ok";
if (myStr.matches("(?s).*\\[\\d+\\s+string:\\s*\\].*")) {
    System.out.println("FOUND");
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/HEQMBT)

The regex will match any number of any characters from the start of string with `.*` (as many as possible) before a `[`+1 or more digits+1 or more whitespace+`string:`+0 or more whitespace+`]`+0 or more any characters up to the end of string.

The `(?s)` internal modifier makes the dot match newline characters, too.

Note we need `.*` on both sides because `.matches()` requires a full string match.

**To match `[3:3]`-like pattern inside larger strings** use:

```
"(?s).*\\[\\d+\\s*:\\s*\\d+\\].*"
```

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/FAY96T)

Remove `\\s*`  if whitespace around `:` is not allowed.